# Comparing the U.S. undergraduate math education to the French "classes préparatoires"

Tags: soft-question, education

Could anyone comment on how the math track of the "classes préparatoires" compares to the U.S. undergraduate major? I took a look at some of the [French entrance exams](http://www.sujets-de-concours.net/concours_filiere.php?concours=xens&filiere=mp) and was rather intimidated. How much do French students learn in those 2 years?! Should 4th year U.S. undergraduate students hypothetically be at a level to take these tests?

Comment: These are exams to ENS/Ecole Polytechnique, and they do not represent general "prépa" level *at all*. Another point is that in these two years students only learn different technical methods of solving problems instead of learning to think. But that is a too long story.

Comment: For those of us who don't read French, could you summarize what the exams cover?

Comment: @O.L. Pinging you so you see my comment above.

Comment: As far as I know, the most brilliant students in France, at the stage of the first year of graduate school, learn much less than those in the United States because they need to practice VERY MUCH to be skilled against concours. I should stress again that the comparison is held between the most brilliant ones, since the variance of levels of U.S. students is very huge. It takes 6 or 4 hours to finish a math exam of ENS concours, and very rare French students can finish them all, so don't be worry if you cannot finish them in 2 hours, say. These concours don't demand you a lot of knowledge.

Comment: @Potato In short, it's an exam based on linear algebra and calculus. Maybe some abstract algebra is also assumed, but no more than rudiments of group theory and field theory. Samples: [this one](http://pomux.free.fr/corriges-1995/pdf/m95lm1ea.pdf) is representative. It demands students to prove Liouville's theorem testing whether the primitive of a specific kind of function is elementary. [This one](http://pomux.free.fr/corriges-2003/pdf/m03lm1e.pdf) is also interesting. It's a special case of [Mordell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell–Weil_theorem) for elliptic curves.

Comment: @Potato [Here](http://www.ens.fr/admission/selection-internationale/rapports-et-sujets-78/?lang=en) are reports (and subjects) of international selections, which are easier than those of concours (only math major is considered), but with English editions and still valuable.